# Java cannot find symbol in scanner

Tags: java, import, symbols

I'm trying to pull information from a text file (which I saved as TextFileHeights) into my method, but I keep getting the error that `File` cannot be found as a symbol. I've tried a lot of different things to fix this bug, like trying to define File as a variable, but I haven't gotten anything to work. What can I do to fix this bug? I have `import java.util.Scanner;` and `import java.io.IOException;` before I define the class, but I haven't been able to compile at all yet.

EDIT:added imports.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LikeSurface{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String TextFileHeights=args[0];

        try{
            if(new File(TextFileHeights).exists()){
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileImputStream(
                            new File(TextFileHeights)
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){ioe.getMessage();}
        }
}
```

Comment: This `ioe.getMessage();` is silently swallowing the exception. Don't do that.

Comment: Where be your import list Mally?

Comment: Show all your impoerts please?

Comment: I added the imports and class definition.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If not, why not? Any decent IDE can take care of the imports for you (and your spelling problems: e.g. `FileImputStream`).

Comment: @Henry Keiter No, I'm not using an IDE. But that spelling change fixed my error, so thank you very much!! I wondered if it was going to be something like that...

Answer (score 2):

You haven't imported `File` class

do this: 
`import java.io.*;` 
or more specifically 
`import java.io.File;`

Comment: I added import java.io.File;
but it gave me two errors--one saying 'cannont find symbol' for 'Input' in my newInputStreamReader( line, plus the error I'm trying to fix (cannot find symbol for 'File' in my new FileImputStream( line).
Then I added both imports that you suggest, and it got rid of the first error, but it kept the second one, so now I'm back at square one.
Could it be that I'm spelling something wrong or have some other simple error?

Comment: @Mally You need to import **all** the classes you're using if they're not part of the `lava.lang` package. This includes classes like `FileInputStream`, which is in `java.io`.

Comment: @Mally as pointed by `henry` you need to import all classes or better would be to go with `import java.io.*;`